# How to "watch" password and confirm password fields in DevTools? - AngularJS forms

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I think the `ng-model`s are `vm.user.password` and `vm.confirmpassword`. The input fields have `id`, `name`, `class` etc. as well.

I want to watch both `password` and `confirmpassword` in DevTools. Or atleast print them in the Console using some command. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect or select the element, in the Developer Console. This will automatically set the variable `$0` to the value of the element.

```
>scope = angular.element($0).scope();
>console.log(scope.vm.user.password);
>console.log(scope.vm.confirmpassword);
```

`scope()` - retrieves the scope of the current element or its parent. Requires [Debug Data](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#disabling-debug-data) to be enabled.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS angular.element Function API Reference - jqLite Extras](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#jquery-jqlite-extras)